# Extract list of names from string with python Regex

Tags: python

i try to extract names from this string but show me empty list

```py
string = """Amy is 5 years old, and her sister Mary is 2 years old. 
    Ruth and Peter, their parents, have 3 kids."""

res = re.findall( r'(?:[A-Z][a-z][\s\.a-z]*)+(?=\s\()', string )

print(res)
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure what you need the groups for. I think what you were trying to do is utilize the capitalization of the names to filter them. This can be done simpler than you suggested:

```py
import re
string = """Amy is 5 years old, and her sister Mary is 2 years old. 
    Ruth and Peter, their parents, have 3 kids."""

res = re.findall( r'[A-Z][a-z]*', string )
print(res)  # ['Amy', 'Mary', 'Ruth', 'Peter']
```

Answer (score 0):

The pattern for the names based on the sentence is

```
[A-Z][a-z]+
```

As the first letter is capital then the rest are not capital ones. Also based on the names in the sentence, the name has at least 2 alphabetical letters.

```
import re 

string = """Amy is 5 years old, and her sister Mary is 2 years old. 
    Ruth and Peter, their parents, have 3 kids."""

x = re.findall(r'[A-Z][a-z]+', string)

print(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, which should find all words beginning with a capital letter:

```
res = re.findall( r'([A-Z]\w+)', string )
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the following code can solve the problem

```
string = """Amy is 5 years old, and her sister Mary is 2 years old. 
            Ruth and Peter, their parents, have 3 kids."""

res = re.findall( r'[A-Z][a-z]*', string )

print(res)
```

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

this would work,

```
res = re.findall(r"\b([A-Z][a-z]+)\b", string)
```

`print(res)` output on that string is:

```
['Amy', 'Mary', 'Ruth', 'Peter']
```

this matches all words starting with a capital letter. it should also be a seperate word so something like "anThony" would not match.